# type 'Future<dynamic> is not subtype of type 'String'

Tags: string, flutter, dart, future, subtype

So i am trying to retrieve data from my firestore document which is an email
I am not understanding how i can save the data as a string when i retrieve it from firestore.
help pls.

Getting error: type 'Future is not subtype of type 'String'  on result: getEmail()
Ps: im new to flutter
my code:

```
getEmail() async{
  String _email = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).email;
  return _firestore.collection('users').document(_email).collection('met_with').document('email').get();
}

...

children: <Widget>[
  BottomSheetText(question: 'Email', result:getEmail()),
  SizedBox(height: 5.0),
....
```

Answer (score 0):

`..document('email)'.get()` will actually return `Future<DocumentSnapshot>`. So `getEmail()` doesn't return a `String`.

You need to get the data out of the `DocumentSnapshot`:

```
Future<String> getEmail() async {
  String _email = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).email;
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await _firestore.collection('users')
    .document(_email)
    .collection('met_with')
    .document('email')
    .get();
  // print("data: ${snapshot.data}"); // might be useful to check
  return snapshot.data['email']; // or another key, depending on how it's saved
}
```

For more info, check out the documentation in the [API reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html)

Now, besides that, `getEmail()` is an async function. Calling it from your widget tree is probably not how you want to handle this.
You'll need to wait for the result of `getEmail()` before you can use it in your UI. A `FutureBuilder` might help:

```
children: <Widget>[
  FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: getEmail(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(!snapshot.hasData) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator(); // or null, or any other widget
      }
      return BottomSheetText(question: 'Email', result: snapshot.data);
    },
  ),
  SizedBox(height: 5.0),
  ... //other
],
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How am I going to use the FutureBuilder to get the value of the string?

Comment: @OmarHajj I edited the answer to add the FutureBuilder

Comment: getting an exception in the method getEmail(): NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []('email'))

Comment: That's probably because the data structure in Firebase is a bit different. Maybe include a screenshot of the firestore date (if it doesn't contain any sensitive information)